# Кто работал с обрезкой миниатюр на yii2 прошу помощи

Tags: yii2, модули

Суть такая: установил виджеты для обрезки изображений

- budyaga/yii2-cropper
- bupy7/yii2-widget-cropbox

Но при работе с большими изображениями они мне обрезают не ту часть и не в том разрешении как на оригинале, может кто посоветовать куда копать?

Answer (score 0):

Для budyaga/yii2-cropper немного доработал код (у меня поле отображения изображения 250px вместо 300px по умолчанию, поэтому по коду 250)

**yii2-cropper/actions/UploadAction.php**

```
    $model->{$this->uploadParam}->name = uniqid() . '.' . $model->{$this->uploadParam}->extension;
    $request = Yii::$app->request;
    $width = $request->post('width', $this->width);
    $height = $request->post('height', $this->height);
    $file = $file->tempName . $request->post('filename');
    $width_original = getimagesize($file)[0];

    $ratioSize = $width_original / 250;

    $w = $width_original / (250 / intval($request->post('w')));
    $answerX = $request->post('x') * $ratioSize;
    $answerY = $request->post('y') * $ratioSize;

    $image = Image::crop(
        $file,
        $w,
        $w,
        [$answerX, $answerY]
    )->resize(
        new Box($width, $height)
    );
```

Немного поясню: не было соотношений загруженного изображения и отображаемого в соответствующем поле и при обрезке использовались координаты отступов от миниатюры а не от оригинала.
Если у кого-то будет желание доработать код под универсальный, прошу скинуть ответ... Надеюсь кому-то помог!